# Non-negative integer solution with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

If you have $x_1+x_2+x_3 \le 22$ and all $x \ge -3$. How would one solve this?

I can think of two ways:

$y_i = x_i + 3$

$\therefore y_1+y_2+y_3 \le 22  + 9 = 31$

$y_4 = 31 - (y_1+y_2+y_3)$

$\implies y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 31$

$= \binom{4+31-1}{31}$

The second way:

$y_i = x_i + 3,\quad 1\le i \le 3$

$\therefore y_1+y_2+y_3 \le31$

$x_4 = 22-(x_1+x_2+x_3)$

$\implies y_1+y_2+y_3+x_4 = 31$

$= \binom{4+31-1}{31}$

What I want to know is, which one is actually the *correct* way to think? The first one makes more sense to me.

Comment: These are equally correct ways to think, as often happens in combinatorics (and all math). The right thing to do is to find as many correct ways to look at a problem as possible, understanding how all the ways are related.

Comment: Since $31-(y_1+y_2+y_3)=22-(x_1+x_2+x_3)$, those are the same thing.